# Finding the first and third moment using MGF

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions, moment-problem

Consider the PDF

$$f(x) = 3x^2, 0≤ x ≤ 1$$

I'm trying to get the first and third moment from this PDF. I found the $E(X)$ using the usual formula to be $3/4$. However, I found the MGF to be
$$\varphi(t)=E(e^{tx})=\frac{({3t^2-6t+6})e^t-6}{t^{3}}$$

To find the first moment, I differentiated and obtained
$$\varphi'(t)=\frac{({3t^3-9t^2+18t-18})e^t+18}{t^{4}}$$

But when substituting $t = 0$, I got $\varphi'(0)=0$ and so $E(X)=0$ which does not agree with what I had above. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You have computed the MGF correctly. You have made a mistake with differentiation. You will get $\frac   34$ if you differentiate and put $t=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, I'm still unable to find the differentiation mistake. Can you point out which part? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have used the formula that $E(X)=\varphi'(0)$. This is true only if $\varphi'$ is defined at $t=0$. In this case, $\varphi'$ is not defined at $t=0$. If you were to substitute $t=0$, you'd obtain $0/0$. Thus, one needs to take the limit
$$E(X)=\lim_{t\to 0} \varphi'(t)=\frac{3}{4}$$
which agrees with what you had.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This may be a dumb question. However, how do you know where the φ′ is defined at? Like how am I supposed to know if I should use E(X)=φ′(0) or if I should take the limit?

Comment: Just subtitute $t=0$. If you can compute and obtain an answer then no limits needed. Otherwise you have to take the limit.